# AWS Ruby SDK permissions for download_files

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the Ruby AWS SDK v3. I can use the method `.content_length` on an instance of [`Object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html), but cannot use `download_file`

The IAM user whose Access Key I am using has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "my_SID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to add an additional permission for the download to succeed? It succeeded when I had full S3 access, but I want to restrict it further.

I also tried setting up the symmetric policy on the bucket itself, to grant this IAM user as the principal the `s3:GetObject` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Nm. I realized what had happened - a get on a non-existent key returns a 403, rather than a 404, when the account only has GetObject privileges.

I had assumed that regardless of the account's access privileges, it would always receive a 404 but I see that that would be a security hole relative to the policy limitation.